# How to blackout future dates

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to blackout future dates from the datepicker. I am using Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit for datepicker.

the code I am trying is

```
DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = DateTime.Now;
```

It gives an error that `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker` does not contain a definition for `DisplayDateEnd`.
Any Ideas, how to blackout or make the future date unselectable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit date range in a DatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031509/limit-date-range-in-a-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible by default: [Limit date range in a DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031509/limit-date-range-in-a-datepicker)

You would have to download the code and modify it. You could add the properties you would like and ask for help if/when you are running into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
datePicker1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.MaxValue));
```

Cheers!

Vinod

Comment: BlackoutDates doesn't work. Of what I have read, it is not possible without changing the datepicker code.