# Set DatePicker's MaxValue in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker

How to set the maxValue of a DatePicker to today's date?? So when scrolling to select the day it won't allow any date from the future.

I have been trying so sort of things but it doesn't work.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031509/limit-date-range-in-a-datepicker

Comment: Thanks..Looks like it is impossible to do so..unless changing the actual source code..Cheers

Comment: You could put in a check when the DatePicker closes, inform the user the date is out of range, and either reset the value to default or reopen the DatePicker. Or, disable the page's save button (if it has one) if the date is out of range, but this can be confusing to the user.