# How to disable dates before today in DatePicker tool in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker, windows-phone

As you can see from the above question, I just want to disable the dates before today in DatePicker tool in Windows Phone. Can any one help me?

Comment: This is a duplicate...

Comment: But it doesn't help. Can you help me with the solution?

Comment: You can able to spot out the duplicate question but it doesn't help. DatePicker tool is something different from WPF toolkit and those functions doesn't help. I think this question can be answered. Put your words reasonably.

Comment: So, you're saying that you are _not_ using the `.NET` [DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468213%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control?

Comment: You are using the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.DatePicker` control. [It does not support date ranges](http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10853). Sorry, but this question is still a duplicate of [Limit date range in a DatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9031509/2596334).

Comment: DatePicker doesn't support Limit Ranges. I think its the proper answer for my question and if i got this answer before, i would have gone for alternate solution. After an hour you got the correct duplicate question and this helps me. Comment only when you find proper duplicate question.

Comment: I clearly specified, its DatePicker control in Windows Phone. And c# tag is irrelevant to my question, I agree.

Comment: Seems like you could create your own DatePickerPage extending DateTimePickerBase and create a constrained UI.  All the code you need to do it is here http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/DateTimePickers/DatePickerPage.xaml and here http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/DateTimePickers/DatePickerPage.xaml.cs then point PickerPageUri to this version rather than the default one...